# Missing Desktop Navigaion

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, web

I have been trying to debug this issue for my [online portfolio](http://andrewduarte.com.au/). Thought I'd turn to you the Stackoverflow community for some assistance and might learn something along the way from the communities finest.

I'm probably missing something obvious. I have been trying to debug an issue where the navigation is not appearing as it should be.

Then the page is being loaded, for a split second, you can see the desktop navigation. 

**Loading Screenshot below:**
[image]

After the page has completed loading, the navigation is not displaying.

**Final load screenshot:**
[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try to use this rule `.tm-navbartm-navbar-overlay:not(.uk-active) {visibility: hidden;}`

Comment: It seems to me that the `margin-top` of your first element(the carousel, -180px) is messing up with it. And hence, that element is getting displayed on top of your navbar. I tried setting `margin-top: 0` and it sort of worked but the layout was not nice afterwards. Start with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question. I was missing a space between two classes.

Backend code:

```
<div class="tm-navbar<?php echo $navbar; ?>"
```

This should of been like this:

```
<div class="tm-navbar <?php echo $navbar; ?>"
```

I do apprecaite all you help. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like theres some jQuery or javascript causing the menu to initially be hidden then to show when you scroll down to a specific point in the page.

it looks like that js or jquery is adding a classes to the div "tm-navbartm-navbar-overlay" called

"tm-navbar-transparent" which controls the menu being hidden, and also the class "uk-animation-slide-top" which controls the menu to show on scroll

first try doing a search for these classes in your project folder and if you see somewhere in a js file where it is controlling the nav, get rid of it.

if that doesnt work revert what you did and try overriding it with simple line of jQuery placed at the top of your main js file

```
$(".tm-navbartm-navbar-overlay").show();
```

Comment: It should be working/appearing something like this theme http://yootheme.com/demo/wordpress/gusto